# JSON dumps UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, json, unicode

I currently have a program which grabs football data from a website and ports it into a `dict`:

```
 dict5[name] = ['To: ' + toteam, 'From: ' + fromteam, 'Price: ' + price, 'Date: ' + newdate]
```

The website is in Portuguese and the native encoding is UTF-8.  The toteam, fromteam, price, and dates are all pre-encoded as UTF-8, just concatenated with the strings in the `dict`.  The program runs just fine and prints to `stdout` with no problem, when when I try and dump it to a json file like this...

```
with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
  f.write(json.dumps(dict5, indent=2))
```

...it comes up with the following error:

```
Traceback:....
C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py, line 238, in dumps
  **kw).encode(obj)
C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py, line 203, in encode
  chunks = list(chunks)
C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py, line 428, in _iterencode
  for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py, line 381, in _iterencode_dict
  yield_encoder(key)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

This is essentially a copy of another program grabbing from the same site, with the same encoding, however that one works fine.

I feel like there's some element of unicode-ness that I'm not grasping.  Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: Always useful: http://bit.ly/unipain

Comment: And how to reproduce that with which data?

Comment: Check that if `name` is a bytestring then it is also encoded as utf-8. Btw, you could use `json.dump(dict5, f)`

Answer (score 3):

> The toteam, fromteam, price, and dates are all pre-encoded as utf-8

Well *there's* your problem. [Use `unicode`s instead.](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Comment: Well they were decoded to unicode then reencoded to the native utf-8 for testing purposes.  Is this wrong?  I don't see how that affects dumping to json

Comment: @user1549620: JSON works with unicode; thus, data you pass to the json module must be unicode too. Don't pass it utf-8 encoded bytestrings.

Comment: Okay I took out all the utf-8 encodings and it worked perfectly.  So as a general rule, is it best to keep it to unicode for json purposes?

Comment: It's best to keep it `unicode` for *all* purposes, unless encoding is *required*.